# How to do a Form post in Angular?

Tags: angular

**payment.php**

```
<p>Redirecting...</p>
<form action="https://biz.traknpay.in/v2/paymentrequest" id="payment_form" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hash; ?>"                   name="hash"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['api_key'];?>"        
name="api_key"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['return_url']; ?>"    name="return_url"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['mode'];?>"           name="mode"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['order_id'];?>"       name="order_id"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['amount'];?>"         name="amount"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['currency'];?>"       name="currency"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['description'];?>"    name="description"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>"           name="name"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>"          name="email"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone'];?>"          name="phone"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['city'];?>"           name="city"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['state'];?>"          name="state"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['zip_code'];?>"       name="zip_code"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['country'];?>"        name="country"/>

<noscript><input type="submit" value="Continue"/></noscript>
</form>
<script>
 function formAutoSubmit () {
 var payform = document.getElementById("payment_form");
 payform.submit();
  }
 window.onload = formAutoSubmit;
 </script>
```

The following is the code To redirect the page to the payment gateway page with the parameters.I tried to implement the same in the angular code but it doesn't work anymore.Geting the template of the payment request page as the response body.

**payment.ts**

```
payment(){
let paymentdata = new FormData();
paymentdata.append('api_key', '69563fbfa-939a-4356d8-92567c-fd2d6e560fa72f');
paymentdata.append('order_id', '11111111111124');
paymentdata.append('mode', 'TEST');
paymentdata.append('amount', '200');
paymentdata.append('currency', 'INR');
paymentdata.append('description', 'BLABLA');
paymentdata.append('name', 'Ajith');
paymentdata.append('email', 'ajith@gmail.com');
paymentdata.append('phone', '8086502009');
paymentdata.append('city', 'tvm');
paymentdata.append('country', 'IND');
paymentdata.append('zip_code', '695505');
paymentdata.append('return_url', 'http://localhost:8100/#/payment/paymentrequest');
paymentdata.append('hash', '8A9DBABCF0CBB9618F74DEA95982DD5D710347B643F45A1E1DFFA42941EACB77C9F8D5C79F7D2EF8FDDFCD944E7EDE36F5D2FF8FBC5D0822A2C79CBDCE73DE05');

  console.log(paymentdata)
  return this.http.post('https://biz.traknpay.in/v2/paymentrequest',paymentdata).map(res=>res).subscribe(res=>
{
  window.open("https://biz.traknpay.in/v2/paymentrequest", "_blank");
  this.body=res;
  console.log(this.body)
   },
err=>{
console.log(err)
})

 }
```

[image: Response body1][image: response body2]

Comment: Maybe you should post your code in angular. This does not seem like angular

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan i have added the typescript  file.

Comment: looks ok...is there any errors?

Comment: @GeekHour no error,im getting a html template as response in the http.post.But in the php code the page is redirecting to the curresponding page.How can i do like in php code

Comment: @AjithManali Is this just a test API key? If not, you should remove sensitive information from the question.

Comment: @masterfloda This test API key wont work

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure you don't expose anything you shouldn't :-)

To get a better understanding of your question: When you call the PHP file, it posts to the payment service, which then redirects to `return_url`, probably sending a status parameter? What exactly does not work? The payment server does not redirect back to your `return_url`?

Comment: Have you checked the content of the response (e.g. `this.body`)? When I post to that URL with your parameters, I get an Error "INVALID-PARAMS - 1024 - The API Key may not be greater than 40 characters.". Unfortunately, the HTTP status is 200, so it does not get handled as an error by angular. You will have to implement your own error handling (the HTML title is "Error", this is something you could check for)

Comment: @masterfloda The following api wont work,thats why u get that error,i can update the question with screenshots of sample response body

Comment: ah, now I understand the problem. The page does not redirect to your `return_url` but is probably the form that handles the payment and only after completed payment it will send the user back to `return_url`.

Comment: You are trying to do a regular HTML `<form>` submit using AJAX. This won't work, this is not what angular is for. Instead of submitting the POST with angular, just do it plain in HTML.